# Error connecting to postgres in node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am trying to connect to postgres from my node project. So far this is my code

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = 'postgress://username:mypssword@localhost:5432/dbname';

var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I get this error:

```
{
    [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect' 

}
```

I really need help on this

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer, you get 2 rep for it, and it helps people in the future figure out what they need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` means that you're trying to connect to something that won't allow it (and thus is refusing the connection).  Make sure your connectionString is correct.  The one issue I can see from here is that it starts with:

```
postgress://
```

instead of

```
postgres://
```

(You have an extra `s`).

Answer (score 4):

it should be `postgres://` not `postgess:`

also you could use an object instead of the string as documented here: [pg.Client](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#new-clientobject-config--client)

Comment: Changing it from a string into an object actually made this one work for me. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue for a local Postgres connection. Here your application is not able to establish a connection with Postgres database. Try this solution for Windows OS, replace string `"localhost"` with `"host.docker.internal"`.

So your new URL will be

```
postgres://DbUser:DbPass@host.docker.internal:5432/DbName
```